# How to add a banner with a message to Report Server Web Portal?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-2019, reportserver

I have an SSRS Report Server web portal running which houses a few hundred reports, my users rely on this data being up to date to do their jobs.

Occasionally my overnight update process will fail, and reports will be updated during the working day, which takes a few hours.

During this time, I want to display a banner on the report server web portal, something like “all reports are being updated, ETA 3pm”.

Is there any way for me to modify the report server html to do that? It doesn’t have to look pretty, I just want to try and avoid all my users calling at once when their reports haven’t updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice simple way would be to just change the site name at the start and end of your job that refreshes the report data.

Use something like

```
UPDATE ReportServer.dbo.ConfigurationInfo 
    SET Value = 'My Company - REFRESH IN PROGRESS ETA 3PM' 
    WHERE [Name] = 'SiteName'
```

and then update again at the end of the job.

As this is simple to automate you could leave it in place in the refresh job.